# Automatic Speech Recognition CTC Loss Suddenly Goes to Infinity After 100 Batches

Tags: python, tensorflow, speech-recognition, infinity, ctc

I have been struggling to create a automatic speech recognition neural network using tensorflow trained on the hugging face mozilla common voice 11 dataset. The model seems to train well for around 100 batches before the loss sudenly goes to infinity.

Here is the code for the data preprocessing:

```
dataset = datasets.load_dataset("mozilla-foundation/common_voice_11_0", "en")
dataset = dataset.remove_columns(['client_id', 'audio', 'up_votes', 'down_votes', 'age', 'gender', 'accent', 'locale', 'segment'])

def prepare_dataset(batch):
    wav_file = batch['path']
    # Remove file name
    split = wav_file.split("\\")
    joined = "\\".join(split[:-1]) + "\\"
    # Get the train number
    complete_path = glob.glob(joined + "*")
    # Combine all the parts
    file = complete_path[0] + "\\" + split[-1]
    batch['path'] = file
    return batch

train_dataset = dataset['train'].map(prepare_dataset).shuffle(len(dataset['train']))
val_dataset = dataset['validation'].map(prepare_dataset).shuffle(len(dataset['validation']))

frame_length = 256
frame_step = 160
fft_length = 384

def load_mp3(wav_file):
    audio = tfio.audio.AudioIOTensor(wav_file, dtype=tf.float32)
    sample_rate = tf.cast(audio.rate, dtype=tf.int64)
    audio = tf.squeeze(audio.to_tensor())
    audio = tfio.audio.resample(audio, rate_in=sample_rate, rate_out=8000)
    audio = tfio.audio.fade(audio, fade_in=1000, fade_out=2000, mode="logarithmic")
    return audio
    
def convert_to_spect(audio):
    spectrogram = tf.signal.stft(
        audio, frame_length=frame_length, frame_step=frame_step, fft_length=fft_length
    )
    spectrogram = tf.abs(spectrogram)
    spectrogram = tf.math.pow(spectrogram, 0.5)
    
    spectrogram = tfio.audio.freq_mask(spectrogram, param=25)
    spectrogram = tfio.audio.time_mask(spectrogram, param=25)
    spectrogram = tfio.audio.freq_mask(spectrogram, param=25)
    spectrogram = tfio.audio.time_mask(spectrogram, param=25)
    
    means = tf.math.reduce_mean(spectrogram, 1, keepdims=True)
    stddevs = tf.math.reduce_std(spectrogram, 1, keepdims=True)
    spectrogram = (spectrogram - means) / (stddevs + 1e-10)
        
    return spectrogram

def process_text(label):
    label = tf.strings.lower(label)
    label = tf.strings.unicode_split(label, input_encoding="UTF-8")
    label = char_to_num(label)
    
    return label

def encode_mozilla_sample(wav_file, label):
    audio = load_mp3(wav_file)
    spectrogram = convert_to_spect(audio)
    label = process_text(label)
    return spectrogram, label
```

And here is the code for the model:

```
def CTCLoss(y_true, y_pred):
    # Compute the training-time loss value
    batch_len = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_true)[0], dtype="int64")
    input_length = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_pred)[1], dtype="int64")
    label_length = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_true)[1], dtype="int64")

    input_length = input_length * tf.ones(shape=(batch_len, 1), dtype="int64")
    label_length = label_length * tf.ones(shape=(batch_len, 1), dtype="int64")

    loss = tf.keras.backend.ctc_batch_cost(y_true, y_pred, input_length, label_length)
    return loss


def build_model(input_dim, output_dim, rnn_layers=5, conv_units=128, rnn_units=128, dropout=0.5):
    input_spectrogram = tf.keras.layers.Input((None, input_dim), name="input")
    
    x = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((-1, input_dim, 1), name="expand_dim")(input_spectrogram)
    # Conv layers
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
        filters=conv_units,
        kernel_size=[11, 41],
        strides=[2, 2],
        padding="same",
        use_bias=False,
        name="conv_1",
    )(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(name="conv_1_bn")(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.ReLU(name="conv_1_relu")(x)
    
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
        filters=conv_units,
        kernel_size=[11, 21],
        strides=[1, 2],
        padding="same",
        use_bias=False,
        name="conv_2",
    )(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(name="conv_2_bn")(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.ReLU(name="conv_2_relu")(x)
    
    x = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((-1, x.shape[-2] * x.shape[-1]))(x)
    # RNN layers
    for i in range(1, rnn_layers + 1):
        recurrent = tf.keras.layers.GRU(
            units=rnn_units,
            activation="tanh",
            recurrent_activation="sigmoid",
            use_bias=True,
            return_sequences=True,
            reset_after=True,
            name=f"gru_{i}",
        )
        x = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(
            recurrent, name=f"bidirectional_{i}", merge_mode="concat"
        )(x)
        x = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(name=f"rnn_{i}_bn")(x)
        if i < rnn_layers:
            x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=dropout)(x)
    # Dense layer
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=rnn_units * 2, activation="gelu", name="dense_1")(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=dropout)(x)
    # Classification layer
    output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=output_dim + 1, activation="softmax", name="output_layer")(x)
    # Model
    model = tf.keras.Model(input_spectrogram, output, name="DeepSpeech_2")
    # Optimizer
    opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
    # Compile the model and return
    model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=CTCLoss)
    return model


# Get the model
model = build_model(
    input_dim=fft_length // 2 + 1,
    output_dim=char_to_num.vocabulary_size(),
    rnn_units=32,
    conv_units=32,
    rnn_layers=5,
    dropout=0.5
)
```

Versions:
tensorflow: 2.10.1

python: 3.9.12

gpu: Nvidia GeForce RTX 3080

OS: Windows 11

cuDNN: 8.1

CUDA: 11.2

I have tried increasing the batch size expecting the model to generalize better but any batch size 256 or higher caused the gpu to run out of memory. The infite loss occurs with any batch size 128 or less. I have also tried increasing the batch size while using less data but the result is the same. I thought that reducing the neural network size would help solve the problem but no matter what, it seems that the loss goes to infinity after reaching a loss of around 200. A few other changes I have tried are activation functions(relu, leakyrelu, gelu), optimizers(SGD, ADAM, ADAMW), and the number of rnn/conv layers.

Note: I have considered using a pretrained model but I have always wanted to successfully create ASR from scratch using tensorflow. Will it even be possible to get even moderately acceptable results using my GPU and data or will I have to resort to using wav2vec?

Another note: I was first inspired to create this project after watching the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YereI6Gn3bM
made by "The A.I. Hacker - Michael Phi" who first convinced me that this was possible. Before I had thought that my computer would not be able to handle this task but after seeing him do this with pytorch, similar computer specs, and the same data, I though that I would be able to do so.

Update:
I have recently tried replacing the 2D Conv layers with a single 1D Conv layer, making the GRU layer not bidirectional, and going back to the AdamW optimizer but nothing has changed.

Comment: Probably not relevant to the specific problem, but be careful using string functions for paths. `os.path` exists for a reason. Possibly more relevant - why disable bias for conv layers? 0.01 seems like a bit high lr for Adam (we all know the best value is 3e-4 ;)), but you run into issues earlier, from my understanding. Also, regularization? I'd re-enable bias first and see if it helps though.

Comment: I removed bias because I thought that since the model was already so large, it would not be needed and would only increase the number of parameters and complexity. After adding bias and reducing the learning rate the model still goes to infinity at around 150 batches and a loss of 600. I also added an l2 kernel regularizer of 0.01 to the dense layer but it was still not successful.

Comment: In general if a `CTCLoss` function is producing infinite loss, or 0 if `zero_infinity=True`, then it means your input sequence is shorter than your output sequence. Can you check the input lengths are longer than your label lengths? (I am assuming here that your labels are your output). 

This is a good explanation: https://voidful.medium.com/understanding-ctc-loss-for-speech-recognition-a16a3ef4da92

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the solution. I just changed the number of neurons in the second to last dense layer to 512 and the model is currently running without error. Now I am just going to have to figure out how to improve the model so I can finally wrap up this project.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).